# Indesign - Blue highlights around my texts

Tags: highlight, adobe-indesign

I do not know how I enabled it but :( cannot close. Tried to reset Indesign but didnt help at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQjG1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have Toggle Style Override Highlighter turned ON.
You can disable it by clicking the [+] Icon at the top of the Paragraph styles panel:

[image: Toggle Style Override Highlighter]

https://indesignsecrets.com/why-is-my-indesign-text-highlighted-in-blue.php